# Rails NoMethodError 'country_select'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I get this error and I don't know why because it should work since in my schema country is a string.

here's my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@studentapplication) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs" id="session-form">
      <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First Name", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Last Name", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :sex, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Sex", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :country, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Country", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :city, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "City", label:false %>
    </div>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Apply", class: "student-bordered" %>
<% end %>
```

The error message tells me:

> undefined method `country_select' for #

Why does it tell me country select? I don't have a country select since my schema looks like this:

schema.rb

```
create_table "studentapplications", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "sex"
  t.string   "country"
  t.string   "city"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a field name 'country', the simple_form will try to use the country_select. You can override that by using the following code,

```
<%= f.input :country, as: :text %>
```

Or, you can add a line in your simple_form.rb initializer,

```
config.input_mappings = { /country/ => :string }
```

Comment: interesting! Thank you I didn't know that. That worked fine. Can you explain the second one please? I did that and it still gave me the error. The first one worked though!

Comment: Once you add the config.input_mappings = { /country/ => :string } inside the simple_form.rb file, you should restart the rails server for it to reflect in the code.